# Notation doesn't work if toolbar is used

Tags: syntax, custom-notation

I am trying the examples on [Notation](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/Notation/tutorial/ComplexPatternsAndAdvancedFeatures.html#4576917) Tutorial

```
In:=  a + b\[LongLeftRightArrow]c // FullForm
Out:= Plus[a,LongLeftRightArrow[b,c]]
```

Then I try to change precedence

```
In:= Notation[a_\[LongLeftRightArrow]b_ \[DoubleLongRightArrow] LongLeftRightArrow[a_,b_]]
In:=  (a + b\[LongLeftRightArrow]c) // FullForm
Out:= Plus[a,LongLeftRightArrow[b,c]]
```

Gives the same output. Expected output is the following as shown in the website

```
LongLeftRightArrow[Plus[a,b], c]
```

But When I copy paste the Notation Syntax from the website it works. But If I use the Notation toolbar it doesn't work

**Update**

```
In:= Notation[RowBox[{a_,TagBox["\[LongLeftRightArrow]",Identity,SyntaxForm->","],b_}] \[DoubleLongRightArrow] LongLeftRightArrow[a_,b_]]
```

Used Tagbox inside yellow box, but no change

Comment: The complete form of the symbol appeared in the tutorial is `TagBox["\[LongLeftRightArrow]", Identity, SyntaxForm -> ","]`, not simply the symbol.

Comment: Please check the update

Comment: I only know one way to get it working(besides manually entering the row box expression): 1. Click the "Full Notation Palette", 2. open "wrapper box" 3. between `a_` and `b_`, insert a box wrapper, then paste that tag box expression into it. I don't know how the documentation directly typed this thing.